# Site está muito lento

Tags: php, mysql

Esse site faz upload de arquivos .torrent, faz download, abre magnet, pega seeds, leechers, etc, porém ele está **MUITO LENTO**, ele demora cerca de 15 segundos para abrir.

o que eu posso fazer para reduzir esse tempo?

```
        if($sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM arquivos_downloads WHERE nome LIKE '%$palavra_chave%' ORDER BY id DESC"))
        {   
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                if($i == $linha['id'] || $i != $linha['id'])
                {   
                    $arq = $linha['nome'];

                    $arq_title = $arq;

                    $arq_nome = substr($linha['nome'], 0, 50);
                    $arq_nome = str_replace("_", " ", $arq_nome);

                    for($icont = 0; $icont <= 100; $icont++)
                    {
                        $arq_nome = str_replace("[".$icont."]", "", $arq_nome);
                        $arq_title = str_replace("[".$icont."]", "", $arq_title);
                    }

                    error_reporting(E_STRICT);

                    ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP');

                    $torrent = new Torrent("Uploads/".$arq.".torrent");
                    $torrentHash = $torrent->hash_info();

                    $SeedsLeechs = obterSeedLeech($torrentHash);
                    $SeedsLeechs = json_decode($SeedsLeechs);

                    if (is_array($SeedsLeechs))
                    {
                        foreach($SeedsLeechs as $anuncios)
                        {
                            $seeds = $seeds + $anuncios->NUM_SEEDERS;
                            $leechers = $leechers + $anuncios->NUM_LEECHERS;
                        }
                    }   
            ?>      
                //AQUI TEM UM MONTE DE DIV QUE NÃO ATRAPALHA
            <?       
                }
                $seeds = 0;
                $leechers = 0;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Lucas, edite a pergunta e deixe somente o código **relevante** para que alguém possa ajudar você.

Comment: Deixei apenas a parte que realmente deixa o site lento

Comment: Você já tentou analisar se o problema esta na consulta ao banco? Para fazer isso, você pode executar a query utilizando o MySQL Workbench (ou similar) ou calcular o tempo antes e depois das chamadas ao banco.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fechar as conexões do PHP assim que você terminar de fazer as `query()`. O jQuery/Javascript coloque em um arquivo separado salvo com extensão `.js`. Cuidado com espaços extremos (sem necessidade). Olhe seu código e pense "isso é mesmo preciso?". Mas o que eu acho mais importante é a questão de fechar as conexões/ações depois de fazer as `query()`, pois fazendo isso, você usará menos memória. Caso tiver muitas imagens no seu site ou imagens de grande tamanho (tipo 1MB, 2MB, etc.) recomendo que use o site `compressor.io` ele te ajudará e muito na questão de imagens.

Comment: Olá, fiz alguns teste e realmente oque gera a lentidão é aquele while, teria alguma forma de deixar aquele while mais leve ??

Comment: O que eu faria é diminuir o número de `loops` que estão dentro do seu `while()` , pois além do `while()` tem um `for()` com 1000 loops e depois um `foreach()`. Tente ver o que vocÊ pode fazer, isso depende da necessidade do seu sistema.

Comment: Realmente, eu concordo com o @AlissonAcioli, diminuir o número de loops dentro do `while`, vendo que o `foreach` nem sequer é dependente, e quanto o `for` acho que pode ser melhorado. Outra coisa é definir o campo `nome` como `INDEX` na tua tabela. Para melhor análise utilize a função [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)